# How To: Disable "add new page" for site page data views?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Using Sharepoint Designer for Sharepoint 2010 is it possible to disable, or better yet remove, the "Add new Page" link at the bottom of a Site Pages Data view?

I'm looking for a checkbox or something that says "disable adding new pages" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

#### using SharePoint Designer

1) open your site to sharepoint desinger 2010.

2) goto List & Libraries > Document libraries > Site Pages

3) open your view in with Edit File in Advanced Mode(Right click on view)

4) search `Toolbar` node tag in XsltListViewWebPart and replace this.

`<Toolbar Type="None"/>`

#### using edit page

1) edit your Default page using Site Action > Edit Page.

2) Edit webpart > Toolbar type > No Toolbar.

[image]

Applied than Okay.

Hops it helps!!!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept your answer. Your solution worked perfectly and thank you for showing me both the GUI version and the code version.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit webpart, and change Tool Bar type as "NO Toolbar" or "Full Toolbar"

Answer (score 0):

below solution is after 2013 SharePoint version,
Click on below site permission

[image]

Click on Advance Permission settings

[image]

Click on the permission level

[image]

Click Read permission and copy and make it as EditOnly and Enable the Edit

[image]

[image]

Create a new grouop and add permission level EditOnly

[image]

Then add user inside the group, now New + icon will not appear on the shared link, only edit.